# Excel Professional Plus 2013 converts random pasted values from dd-mm-yyyy to m/d/yyyy format

Tags: microsoft-excel

There's two sides to this question, SQL Server and Excel. I'm asking this question in an Excel forum because I'm pretty sure this stems from the Excel side.

I have a SQL Server select statement that returns -- among other things -- a column in [dd-mm-yyyy] format. Everything looks good in SQL Server Management Studio and when I export it as a CSV and view it in notepad. But whether I copy and paste into Excel (Professional Plus 2013) or import the file into Excel, the same symptom happens: random dates are converted from [dd-mm-yyyy] format into [m/d/yyyy] format.

My requirement is to give this report in Excel to the customer in the specified format with the date strongly typed as a date field (and not text).

Here two images (SQL Server and Excel) showing how the data changes. Is there some setting in Excel I can set to prevent this from happening?

[image: Screenshot showing how random dates get corrupted]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not random. The dates that are keeping the format are being treated by Excel as Text (left aligned). The ones with different format are treated as numbers (dates - right aligned).

My guess is that your regional settings are set to use M/D/YYYY format. Hence, only dates that comply with this format are imported as number.

Examples 24-09-1998 does not comply with M/D/YYYY, therefore is treated as text. 01-06-2000 will be imported as date but it will be the 6th of January instead of the 1st of June.

Check your regional settings.

After correctly importing all dates as number (date) you can apply whatever date format you want. The one you want is `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Comment: I changed my Windows regional setting to Italian and the values pasted into Excel flawlessly. I saved and closed the file, changed my OS back to English (United States) and after opening the file, the date format did not persist. This suggests to me that Excel changes the date format based on what the OS regional setting is.

Comment: After correctly importing the data to excel, enforce the date format. Choose Format Cells (Ctrl+1) then add the intended format `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Comment: That was the final step. I had to enter it as a custom format. I also checked each cell in the column with =Type(col) and verified that all cells were Type=1 (numeric).  This last step did the job. I switch my Regional setting back to normal and re-opened the file. The format persisted.